# How to understand the $\pi(a|s)$ in Bellman's equation

Tags: machine-learning, markov-process, reinforcement-learning

I was reading "Reinforcement Learning, An Introduction" by Sutton and one of the variations of Bellman's Equation in the book confuses me:
[image]

Equation (3.14) has the term $\sum_a{\pi(a|s)}$ in it. According to my understanding, the $\pi$ stands for policy and it should be a function that takes in states and returns an action. Then how do I make sense of the $\pi(a|s)$ notation? It seems to take in action as one of its parameters as well?

Answer (score 2):

In the book's appendix Summary of Notation

> $\pi(a|s)$ is probability of taking action $a$ in state $s$ under
>   stochastic policy $\pi$

[image]

Comment: I'll upvote this if you convert the picture into text. As is, it can't be found through search or used in text-to-speech

Answer (score 1):

$\pi(a|s)$ represent a policy rule.

The value function is a mean reward that agent could get out from the environment, starting from state s and following policy $\pi$ onward. The value function is defined simply as an expected return, conditioned on the state an agent currently stands in.

The given equation consist of two parts - policy stochasticity

> $\sum_{a} \pi(a|s)$

and environmental stochasticity

> $\sum_{r,s'} p(r,s'|s,a)$

Another way to understand $\pi(a|s)$ is to visualize this domain using backup diagram

[image]
(Slides of [Practical RL course](https://github.com/yandexdataschool/Practical_RL))